# Manejo de arreglos multidimensional codeigniter

Tags: array, codeigniter

Buen día. 
Tengo un arreglo para guardar la información de la sesión que utilizare, me lo envía arreglo multidimencional pero no he podido acceder a los datos, solo los puedo ver mediante print_r.
anexo resultado de print_r. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su apoyo, saludos!!!

Comment: Hola Ismael, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. También puedes revisar [como crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu array esta guardado en la variable $user, para acceder debes utilizar dos indices. El primero es el de datousuario, y el segundo el campo que quieres acceder. Por ej, para acceder al nombre:

**$user['datousuario']['nombre']**

Ten en cuenta que para hacer esto debes conocer las claves (indices) del segundo nivel. Si necesitas una lista de estos indices, puedes obtenerla con:

**array_keys($user['datousuario'])**

Esto ultimo te devolveria un array tal que asi:

```
array(
    '__ci_last_regenerate',
    'logged_in',
    'username',
    'usuariovalido',
    ...
)
```

Comment: Gracias FederHico, tengo que estudiar la parte de arreglos multidimencionales, ya que con codeigniter son muy necesarios.